# MySql Group By Use Index

Tags: mysql, grouping

If i have a table in **Mysql** which has a multi column index on the fields (`phone_number`, `name`)

While querying this table if i just `group by` on `phone_number` will this index be used?

And if i performing any operation involving just phone_number will the index be used?

And if i want to `group by phone_number`, name then will this index be used?

Comment: How the database internally executes your query is hard to tell. The best way to find out what is going on is to test it and Look at the execution plan. You can do this by EXPLAIN. (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html)

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, MySQL is able to perform GROUP BY using index access.

> the  preconditions for using indexes for GROUP BY are that all GROUP
>   BY columns reference attributes from the same index, and that the
>   index stores its keys in order.

this mean that in your case is possibile use index for both your question

You can find more here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html